# ElasticSearch - Get Multiple Occurrences

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say I have some data in elasticsearch and I would like to retrieve all of the records where a particular field is present more than once. For example:

```
{id:1, name: "bob", "age":30}
{id:2, name: "mike", "age":20}
{id:3, name: "bob", "age":30}
{id:4, name: "sarah", "age":40}
{id:5, name: "mike", "age":35}
```

I want a query that would return multiple occurrences by name. So it should return the following records:

```
{id:1, name: "bob", "age":30}
{id:2, name: "mike", "age":20}
{id:3, name: "bob", "age":30}
{id:5, name: "mike", "age":35}
```

So id: 4 is excluded since the name 'sarah' only occurs in one doc. A more preferable return would be something like:

```
{"name": "bob", "count":2}
{"name": "mike", "count":2}
```

but can work with the first query return if its easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use what is called `Aggregations` in Elasticsearch. If you're just looking for duplicate names, you can use a [`Terms Aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

Here's an example. You can set up your data like this:

```
PUT testing/_doc/1
{
  "name": "bob",
  "age": 30
}

PUT testing/_doc/2
{
  "name": "mike",
  "age": 20
}

PUT testing/_doc/3
{
  "name": "bob",
  "age": 30
}

PUT testing/_doc/4
{
  "name": "sarah",
  "age": 40
}

PUT testing/_doc/5
{
  "name": "mike",
  "age": 20
}
```

Then run your aggregation:

```
GET testing/_doc/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "duplicates": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.keyword",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you a response like this:

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 5,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "duplicates": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "bob",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "mike",
          "doc_count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The important part is the `aggregations.duplicates.buckets` where the `"name"` is shown in the `"key"`.